# Allow a SFTP user to create new files, but not modify or delete them

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, sftp, restic

I am setting up a server to host my [restic](https://restic.readthedocs.io/) backup. The backup will be done via SFTP. During backup, restic has no need to delete or modify any files, so I decided that I would like to protect against the user being able to do that. That way, anybody with access to the machine being backed up, can't easily compromise my backups.

I want to use chroot to restrict access to just the backup repository for that user.
The only thing I came up with is running `chmod -R 444 $BACKUP_LOCATION && chown -R root:root $BACKUP_LOCATION` with cron every minute, but it seems hacky.

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by the mix of ***xattr*** (extended attributes for linux ) & ***inotify utility*** :

One way to achieve this can be using extended attributes :

1- Set the correct permissions on your directory so anyone can create files within it and to '*cd*' to it :

```
sudo chmod 777 $BACKUP_LOCATION
```

2- Install **inotify-tools** ( It depends on your OS ), this utility will make possible to watch the changes made on  $BACKUP_LOCATION and here it's the case of **new files** created detection :

3- Edit & Save the below script, Here the new files will have as extended attribute **immutable** (that means they cannot be removed or edited even by root) and also **r--,r--,r--** permissions :

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUPDIR="/path/your/backup/directory"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${BACKUPDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
    chmod 444 "$NEWFILE"
    chattr +i "$NEWFILE"
done
```

4- Create a service under *'/etc/systemd/system/backuprotection.service'* 
 that will run your script as a daemon because it needs to turn in the background and also to make are sure that the script is keeps running even after a reboot :

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for backup protection

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/path/your/script.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

5- Reload the new configuration from disk :

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

6- Enable your service, so it will start once the systemd has booted :

```
sudo systemctl enable backuprotection
```

7- Start and check the status of *backuprotection* service :

```
sudo systemctl start script.sh
sudo systemctl status backuprotection
```

8- Check the new created files xattributes & permissions under $BACKUP_LOCATION :

```
# Permissions should be r--,r--,r--
ls -ltr $BACKUP_LOCATION
# "i" should be set on the 5th position
lsattr $BACKUP_LOCATION
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question, however - shouldn't the directories have 666 set? Otherwise, new files can't be created in the newly created directories.

Comment: You have to edit the script and use a recursive function because inotify is not recursive and check whether it's directory or file ;  if it's a directory it will have 666 so new files can be created there.